# Insert new column on loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to insert a `<td></td>` on each row.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/member-area/product/link-product-group',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    if (json.status == "success") {
      $('#variants').append(json.html);
    } else if (json.status == "addGroups") {
      $('#ajax-variant thead tr').append('<th>' + json.grp + '</th>');
      $('<td><input type="text" id="variant-input" name="' + json.grp + '" value="" class="form-control flat"/></td>').each(function() {
        $(this).insertBefore('#ajax-variant tbody tr td:last');
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Problem: It is only inserting in to the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping you can simply use

```
$('#ajax-variant tbody tr td:last-child').before('<td><input type="text" id="variant-input" name="' + json.grp + '" value="" class="form-control flat"/></td>');
```